# BottomNavbar component not rendering outside of scrollview

Tags: javascript, android, css, reactjs, react-native

I'm very new to react native. I'm using react native paper for creating a bottom navbar for my app. The navbar though, doesn't render if I Put it outside the scrollview. I want the navbar to be fixed and not scrolled.

This is how navbar looks like:

```
import React from "react";
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from "react-native-paper/react-navigation";
import Octagon from "./pinnedChats/flower";
import Rectangle from "./pinnedChats/reactangle";
import { Colors } from "react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen";

const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();

export default function BottomNavbar() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      barStyle={{ backgroundColor: "#000", }}
      activeColor="#fff"
    >
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Octagon} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={Rectangle} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

This is my app code:

```
import React from "react";
import {
  ScrollView,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  AppRegistry,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
} from "react-native";

import { PaperProvider } from "react-native-paper";
import { name as appName } from "./app.json";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";

import Chat from "./src/chat";
import PinnedChats from "./src/pinnedChats/round";
import Octagon from "./src/pinnedChats/flower";
import Rectangle from "./src/pinnedChats/reactangle";
import BottomNavbar from "./src/bottomNavbar";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <PaperProvider>
        <StatusBar animated={true} backgroundColor="#000" />
        <View
          style={{
            height: 50,
            width: "100%",
            backgroundColor: "#000",
            justifyContent: "center",
            alignItems: "center",
          }}
        >
          <Text style={{ color: "#fff" }}>soul</Text>
        </View>
        <ScrollView>
          <View
            style={{
              width: "100%",
              justifyContent: "space-evenly",
              alignItems: "center",
              height: 500,
            }}
          >
            <View
              style={{
                width: "90%",
                flexDirection: "row",
                alignItems: "center",
                justifyContent: "space-between",
              }}
            >
              <PinnedChats />
              <PinnedChats />
            </View>
            <View
              style={{
                width: "90%",
                flexDirection: "row",
                alignItems: "center",
                justifyContent: "space-between",
              }}
            >
              <PinnedChats />
              <Octagon size={130} color={"#fff"} />
            </View>
            <Rectangle />
          </View>

          <Chat
            message={{
              name: "Robert Jack",
              subtext: "It came to my notice that, you aren't...",
            }}
            newMessage={false}
            notif={{
              newMessageTime: "4:30pm",
              default: "Yesterday",
              incoming: false,
            }}
          />
          <Chat
            message={{
              name: "Rahul",
              subtext: "Hey wassup? I was wondering if you could ..",
            }}
            newMessage={false}
            notif={{
              newMessageTime: "4:30pm",
              default: "Yesterday",
              incoming: false,
            }}
          />
          <Chat
            message={{ name: "Robert Jack", subtext: "lol that's just insane" }}
            newMessage={true}
            notif={{
              newMessageTime: "4:30pm",
              default: "Yesterday",
              incoming: true,
            }}
          />
          <Chat
            message={{ name: "Robert Jack", subtext: "sup bro?" }}
            newMessage={true}
            notif={{
              newMessageTime: "11:00am",
              default: "Yesterday",
              incoming: true,
            }}
          />

          <Chat
            message={{
              name: "alex",
              subtext: "Hey! im on my way..",
            }}
            newMessage={false}
            notif={{
              newMessageTime: "11:00am",
              default: "Yesterday",
              incoming: false,
            }}
          />
        </ScrollView>
        <BottomNavbar />
      </PaperProvider>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: "#000",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});


AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

also, if I apply some styling using the container to scroll view , the nav bar isn't visible

`<ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.container}>`

[image: With no style applied and bottomnav moved inside scroll view]
[image: With style applied bottomnav moved inside scroll view]

Comment: I got a way around this :
so I enclosed the bottomNav into a view outside the scroll view and gave the height same as that of tht nav.
is there a better way?